# Retrieve Column names From one table that contain 'report'

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I need to know the column names of my table `exchangecondition` that contains "report" in their names. I tried to use `USER _TAB_COLUMNS` but that didn't work, because I get `no rows selected` with this query:

```
select *  from USER_TAB_COLUMNS;
```

However, if I could get rows when I use `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, I can use this query:

```
SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'exchangecondition' and  column_name like '%report%'.
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: do u mean select * doesnt work and select column_name work ? Your question is unclear

Comment: Unless you used quoted identifiers when creating the table, you need to supply the table name and (partial) column name in uppercase. But if you can't see anything in that view, which schema owns 'your' table?

Comment: @Shankar yes I type select *  from USER_TAB_COLUMNS; as a query I don't get any row

Comment: You're right @AlexPoole I use instead of USER_TAB_COLUMNS I use all_tab_columns and  the table name and  column name in uppercase and it worked thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using user_tab_columns, use all_tab_columns, provide table name and column name in upper case, provide owner name (incase you know it already).

Comment: I use instead of USER_TAB_COLUMNS I use all_tab_columns and  the table name and  column name in uppercase and it worked thanks for your answer

Comment: just I need to know how can I search of the col of EXCHANGECONDITION table which contains data can you give me the query please ?!

Comment: what do you mean by "col of EXCHANGECONDITION table which contains data"?? You want to query your table  EXCHANGECONDITION based upon some column value?